# How to show suggestions while searching in iOS?

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode

I am working with Swift 3. I am basically using an API to search for images from the web. I want to add suggestions to my searchBar when any word is being entered. For example when I search "Sa", I get suggestions like "Sand", "Samsung", "Sail", etc. Any suggestions as to how I can implement this?

The output I get after executing the query is in JSON format.

[I want my Search Bar to look something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roRTQ.png)

Comment: is suggestions comes from your api ?

Comment: No, I don't think any suggestions come from my API.

Comment: or try this third party library : https://github.com/gaurvw/MPGTextField

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways.

You can use the KeyboardAccessory. The shows a view over the keyboard (where auto complete is normally places) which you can use this way you like, e.g. add three buttons which will trigger the input of the correct suggestion. Apple provides an example here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/KeyboardAccessory/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009462-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Another way is just by placing an view (most likely table view) on your current view, place just below the input filed, either with a fixed height of e.g. 3 items or till the keyboard. For this approach you can have a look into this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/336/auto-complete-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-auto-complete-with-custom-values

Comment: Will any of these methods show me the words which have a result? @Nef10

Comment: Yes. E.g. for the second tutorial: you put your list of all words you want to autocomplete in the `pastUrls` variable in the `searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring` method.

Comment: I guess creating a list of all the word which I want to autocomplete won't be possible as only after I get the whole word I can execute the query.

Comment: Sorry, but than your question is way to broad. You should ask a question how to generate a list of words to autocomplete separate form the one how to present it.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this to search i am searching in array of dictionary with name i show the all result search in my tableview below the UISearchBar

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
{
    let namePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[c] %@", searchText)
    if HotelData.count > 0
    {
        searchData = (HotelData as NSArray).filtered(using: namePredicate) as [AnyObject]
        tlbSearch.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand that I have to create an array with some words for which the SearchBar can check. But what I am trying to get as suggestions are the words which have results linked to them.

Comment: @BalvanshHeerekar you need to show it in keyword suggestion in keyboard

Comment: @BalvanshHeerekar i see the attached your screenshot if you set the tableview exactly the below where searchbar place put initially hidden after the searching you can display the tableview work like as you want